# add_meta_box() to Category Edit Screen?

Tags: plugin-development

I've got a plugin that attaches itself to both the post and page editors to read and write to the post_content object. I'd like to also attach my plugin to the category manager edit screen.

In the code below, lines 1 and 2 attach it to the post and page editor, but line 3, a shot in the dark, is not yet doing the trick. Any ideas on the proper way to do it?

```
if ( function_exists('add_meta_box') ) { 
    add_meta_box('My-plugin', __('My plugin'), 'My_plugin_callback', 'post', 'side', 'high');
    add_meta_box('My-plugin', __('My plugin'), 'My_plugin_callback', 'page', 'side', 'high'); 
//???   add_meta_box('My-plugin', __('My plugin'), 'My_plugin_callback', 'category', 'side', 'high');
}
```

Comment: Check my answer on this topic on stackoverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/a/36033019/1835470

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that even if you add that meta box at the bottom of the category edit you will still have the problem of meta table for categories, and i bet that your meta_box 'save' function saves as postmeta data table.

However this can be done using the options table here is an [how to add extra fields to categories](http://en.bainternet.info/2011/wordpress-category-extra-fields)

Hope this helps

Comment: @בניית אתרים: Thanks. I've already got a few extra fields on my category edit screen using the "edit_category_form" add_filter. I'm just trying to see if there's an add_meta_box hook on that screen to make this as simple as it was to add the interface to the post and page editors.

Comment: @Scott B: I'm afraid it's not that simple but its not that hard either, if you already have a extra fields then create a new function based on your meta-box display function, and change it a bit to display on the category edit form using 'edit_category_form' filter and create another function based on your meta-box save function and change it a bit to save on the category extra fields instead of postmeta and hook that to 'edited_category' filter

Comment: That sounds like a plan. Let me work on it and see what I can come up with. Thanks for taking time to explain that.

Comment: +1 for best answer considering there the answer to the original question appears to be "No" :-)

Comment: This answer and the tutorial link provided are quite old and contain deprecated stuff - to new stuff - check my answer on this topic on stackoverflow :) :: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36033019/1835470

Comment: @Brainternet Can someone please explain what is wrong with using the `termmeta` table? And why is it always empty? What are the `get_term_meta`, `add_term_meta`, `update_term_meta` and `delete_term_meta` functions for if not to manipulate term meta-data with the term being either a certain tag, category or custom taxonomy? I'm really having a hard time understanding.